# Override socket.error in Python

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling

Is it possible to override `socket.error`?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
class SocketError(socket.error):
    def __init__(self, message , error):
        super(SocketError , self).__init__(message)
        self.message = message  
        self.error = error
```

---

**Test**
Heres the test version:

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 80
address = (host ,port)
server = socket.socket(2 , 1)
try:
    server.bind(address)
except SocketError:
    print SocketError.message
```

running it without permission rises Error13 : Permission Error.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "override", and why you want to do it. While you can probably do it, it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: @user235712 adding some new functionalities ... make it more OOP and other stuff.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of redesign you really shouldn't be trying to apply to someone else's code. Are you trying to give its constructor extra arguments? How would the code that constructs this exception know to pass it more arguments?

Comment: @user235172 Lets say I want to create and pass 10 sockets at a time, each of them numbered from 1 to 10 , one of them raises error. I want to pass its number to the error something like:
SocketError: [Errno 13] Permission denied | Socket 8

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to happen. You might be able to do it with a custom socket wrapper or subclass, but I would recommend other ways of keeping track of that information.